# Mouse click event for JFrame change

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to change a `JFrame` window to another one with `MouseEvent`. Code is below.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
String pass;
String user;
user = txtUser.getText();
pass = txtPass.getText();

if(pass.equals("********") && user.equals("**********") )
{
  ??????????
}
else{
    lblDisplay.setText("Please try again.");
```

Comment: You have not added your code.

Comment: Code is Updated.

Comment: @ErmanALTIKULAÇ What do you mean you need to change to the other one? Is that another `JFrame` or a `JPanel` in the same window?

Comment: I mean another jframe

Comment: Don't use a MouseListener. A JButton is designed to be used with an ActionListener. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Further tips: 1) Heed the advice of @camickr re an `ActionListener`. 2) A password field should be a `JPasswordField` which deprecates the `getText()` method as it is insecure. 3) Since it is for a log-in, this 'frame' should likely be a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` instead. 4) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1):

If you need to go to another `JFrame` if the `username` and `password` matches, you can do as follows.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    String pass;
    String user;
    user = txtUser.getText();
    pass = txtPass.getText();

    if(pass.equals("********") && user.equals("**********"))
    {
        // Here you can dispose the current window
        this.dispose(); // Or you can use this.setVisible(false);

        // Then call your next window to appear
        new YourNextWindow().setVisible(true);

        // And of course you can create an object for that window,

        YourNextWindow yourNextWindow = new YourNextWindow();
        yourNextWindow.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        lblDisplay.setText("Please try again.");
    }
}
```

It's better to use `this.dispose();` instead of making the `JFrame` invisible `setVisible(false)` as it will be still running without any use.

**UPDATE**

As [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) said it is best to use `ActionListener` instead of `MouseListener`.

```
public void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Don't use a MouseListener. A JButton is designed to be used with an ActionListener.